# unicode string in file contain different

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, utf-16

My system is fedora. From some reason .The last field of one record is **a unicode string**       (use memcpy copy data from a guest machine in qemu) . The unicode string is windows regedit key name.

> smss.exe|NtOpenKey|304|4|4|0|\^@R^@e^@g^@i^@s^@t^@r^@y^@\^@M^@a^@c^@h^@i^@n^@e^@\^@S^@y^@s^@t^@e^@m^@\^@C^@u^@r^@r^@e^@n^@t^@C^@o^@n^@t^@r^@o^@l^@S^@e^@t^@\^@C^@o^@n^@t^@r^@o^@l^@\^@S^@e^@s^@s^@i^@o^@n^@ ^@M^@a^@n^@a^@g^@e^@r^@
>   smss.exe|NtClose|304|4|4|0|System|NtOpenKey|4|0|2147484532|0|\^@R^@e^@g^@i^@s^@t^@r^@y^@\^@M^@a^@c^@h^@i^@n^@e^@\^@S^@y^@s^@t^@e^@m^@\^@C^@u^@r^@r^@e^@n^@t^@C^@o^@n^@t^@r^@o^@l^@S^@e^@t^@
>   services.exe|NtOpenKey|680|624|636|0|\^@R^@E^@G^@I^@S^@T^@R^@Y^@\^@M^@A^@C^@H^@I^@N^@E^@\^@S^@y^@s^@t^@e^@m^@\^@C^@u^@r^@r^@e^@n^@t^@C^@o^@n^@t^@r^@o^@l^@S^@e^@t^@\^@S^@e^@r^@v^@i^@c^@e^@s^@

Here is the some of hex code: use '|' as split char. The first 6 fields was ascii sting .The last field is a window unicode string (which I think it is utf-16 code) .

> 0000000    6d73    7373    652e    6578    4e7c    4f74    6570    4b6e
>   0000010    7965    337c    3430    347c    347c    307c    5c7c    5200
>   0000020    6500    6700    6900    7300    7400    7200    7900    5c00
>   0000030    4d00    6100    6300    6800    6900    6e00    6500    5c00
>   0000040    5300    7900    7300    7400    6500    6d00    5c00    4300
>   0000050    7500    7200    7200    6500    6e00    7400    4300    6f00
>   0000060    6e00    7400    7200    6f00    6c00    5300    6500    7400
>   0000070    5c00    4300    6f00    6e00    7400    7200    6f00    6c00
>   0000080    5c00    5300    6500    7300    7300    6900    6f00    6e00
>   0000090    2000    4d00    6100    6e00    6100    6700    6500    7200

I will use python to parse it and insert it a db . Here is how i handle

```py
def parsecreate(filename):
    sourcefile = codecs.open("data.db",mode="r",encoding='utf-8')
    cx = sqlite3.connect("sqlite.db")
    cu = cx.cursor()
    cu.execute("create table data(id integer primary key,command text, ntfunc text, pid text, ppid text, handle text, roothandle text, genevalue text)")
    eachline = []
    for lines in sourcefile:
        eachline = lines.split('|')
        eachline[-1] = eachline[-1].strip('\n')
        eachline[-1] = eachline[-1].decode('utf-8')

        cu.execute("insert into data(command,ntfunc,pid,ppid,handle,roothandle,genevalue) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(eachline[0],eachline[1],eachline[2],eachline[3],eachline[4],eachline[5],eachline[-1]) )

    cx.commit()
    cx.close()
```

I will got wrong :

> File "./parse1.py", line 18, in parsecreate
>      for lines in sourcefile:
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 684, in next
>      return self.reader.next()
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 615, in next
>      line = self.readline()
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 530, in readline
>      data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 477, in read
>      newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte **0xd0** in position 51: invalid continuation byte

Becuase the unicode string may contain a byte the utf8 not know it.
 How Can read the last field rightly?

Simply to say . There is a unicode string in not a utf-16 encode file, How can make the field rightly be insert into the db? Python read a file use one encoding style. Can I just read origin bytes .Can combine these bytes into a unicode string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data file is not a text-only file so open the file as binary and decode the text fields explicitly.  I had to manipulate the data quite a bit to get back what I think was the original binary data.  It looks like the original data may have been a `sqlite3.exe` dump similar to my final output below, except the data for the final field was stored as a UTF-16-encoded BLOB instead of TEXT.

Note that parsing by lines and splitting by '|' may encounter problems if the UTF-16 data contains the bytes representing '\n' or '|', but I'll ignore that for now.

Here's my test:

```py
from binascii import unhexlify
import sqlite3

data = unhexlify('''\
6d73 7373 652e 6578 4e7c 4f74 6570 4b6e
7965 337c 3430 347c 347c 307c 5c7c 5200
6500 6700 6900 7300 7400 7200 7900 5c00
4d00 6100 6300 6800 6900 6e00 6500 5c00
5300 7900 7300 7400 6500 6d00 5c00 4300
7500 7200 7200 6500 6e00 7400 4300 6f00
6e00 7400 7200 6f00 6c00 5300 6500 7400
5c00 4300 6f00 6e00 7400 7200 6f00 6c00
5c00 5300 6500 7300 7300 6900 6f00 6e00
2000 4d00 6100 6e00 6100 6700 6500 7200'''.replace(' ','').replace('\n',''))

# OP's data dump must have been decoded from the original data
# as little-endian words, and is missing a final 0x00 byte.
# Byte-swapping and adding missing zero byte to get back what
# was likely the original binary data.
data = ''.join(a+b for a,b in zip(data[1::2],data[::2])) + '\x00'

with open('data.db','wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

def parsecreate(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as sourcefile:
        with sqlite3.connect("sqlite.db") as cx:
            cu = cx.cursor()
            cu.execute("create table data(id integer primary key,command text, ntfunc text, pid text, ppid text, handle text, roothandle text, genevalue text)")
            eachline = []
            for line in sourcefile:
                eachline = line.split('|')
                eachline[-1] = eachline[-1].decode('utf-16le')
                cu.execute("insert into data(command,ntfunc,pid,ppid,handle,roothandle,genevalue) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(eachline[0],eachline[1],eachline[2],eachline[3],eachline[4],eachline[5],eachline[-1]) )

parsecreate('data.db')
```

Output:

```
C:\>sqlite3 sqlite.db
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from data;
1|smss.exe|NtOpenKey|304|4|4|0|\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

Comment: Thank you very mush. As i just come home ,I will test tomorrow . I can find two difference. 1.read with mode 'b' 2 Because last filed was ready a utf-16le  , just decode it to unicode string. By the way , the file data.db you write is "mssse.exN|OtepKnye3|404|4|0|\| a string".I think the problem was  caused by i just copy a little part of the file. it should be like "**.exe|NtOpenKey|**".

Comment: Yes, it would be better to have the original raw data, or at least dumped as bytes instead of what I suspect was little-endian words.  I updated my answer to descramble your data.

Comment: I hava a problem to handle the '\n', if i don't write a '\n' to the end of a entry recode .How can i read a line from the file . If i write a '\n', then  : 1  don't use `eachline[-1] = eachline[-1].strip('\n')` cause `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 132: truncated data` 2 use `eachline[-1] = eachline[-1].strip('\n')` I wonder weather there is Possibility it will delelte  a byte inside the unicode string .

Comment: I got misunderstand .It  may caused by a unicode string contain '0x0A',then `for lines in file ` may get a wrong line (because it readline until get '\n')